# Eclipse ignores ECLIPSE_HOME

Tags: linux, java, fedora, environment-variables, eclipse

I have set the `ECLIPSE_HOME` environment variable to `/home/stud/me/.eclipse`. In this dir I have an `eclipse.ini` file. However when I start Eclipse it just uses the `eclipse.ini` file in the installation dir.

Here is what I checked:

- I double checked and made sure the executable is actually called `eclipse`.
- I put the line `export ECLIPSE_HOME='/home/stud/me/.eclipse'` in the `/home/stud/me/.profile` file
- The `/home/stud/me/.profile` script gets called on login (I start a few services through that file which work)
- Manually specifying the `/home/stud/me/.eclipse/eclipse.ini` via the command line works. Without it doesn't
- Running `echo $ECLIPSE_HOME` outputs `/home/stud/me/.eclipse`
- And running `export` lists `ECLIPSE_HOME` with the correct value

General information: I'm using Fedora 26 with the XFCE4 desktop environment. The computers I'm using a part of a university network, so I can only work with my system files and I of course do not have administrator permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't support an ECLIPSE_HOME environment variable. The eclipse.ini is always read from the same directory as the installation.

See [Eclipse multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html) for more details about various types of Eclipse install.

You can specify `--launcher.ini location` as a command line argument to specify the ini location

Comment: According to https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini it does care about that variable.

Comment: I can't find anything in the source code that looks for an ECLIPSE_HOME

Comment: Then that wiki page is misleading. Since it looks official it might be a bug. What do you think?

Comment: Checking the source I notice the `--launcher.ini` option which you can specify to set the ini location. This is documented in the Eclipse help. Added to answer.

Comment: I'm currently using that as a temporary solution, yet I'm still puzzled as to why this documented feature clearly ins't working. Since you appear to be familiar with the code would you consider creating an appropriate bug report?